# Суммировать значения ключей

Tags: javascript

как мне суммировать значения одинаковых ключей?

```js
[{period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 70883.3, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "Income"}, {period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -2955.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"}, {period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 0, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"}, {period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 8555.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"}, {period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -2955.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"}, {period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -9761.48, refund: 14, sold_items: 4149, class: "FBA_Fees"}
```

Comment: Такой пример объекта, как вы показали, невозможен. На одном уровне вложенности, каждый ключ уникален.

Comment: Хорошо, а если так [{period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 70883.3, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "Income"},
{period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -2955.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"},
{period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 0, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"},
{period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 8555.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"},
{period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -2955.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"},
{period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -9761.48, refund: 14, sold_items: 4149, class: "FBA_Fees"}]

Comment: Другое дело. Вот это и напишите в вопросе.

Comment: @Deonis, возможен, но просто значение будет переписано

Comment: @entithat, если вы берёте в расчет, когда руками в коде можно написать любую ахинею, то да. )) В ином случае, я повторю, что это невозможно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let test =  [{period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 70883.3, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "Income"}, {period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -2955.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"}, {period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 0, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"}, {period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 8555.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"}, {period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -2955.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS"}, {period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -9761.48, refund: 14, sold_items: 4149, class: "FBA_Fees"}];
let result = {};

test.forEach((el, i) => {    
    if (!result[el.class])
        result[el.class] = 0;
        
    result[el.class] += el.revenue;
});

console.log(result);
```

Да, можно через `reduce`, но это будет не оч. читаемо, кмк.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Вариант через `reduce` с динамическим ключем:

```js
const data = [
  { period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 70883.3, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "Income" },
  { period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -2955.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS" },
  { period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 0, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS" },
  { period: "2021-04-01", revenue: 8555.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS" },
  { period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -2955.403, refund: 0, sold_items: 4206, class: "COGS" },
  { period: "2021-04-01", revenue: -9761.48, refund: 14, sold_items: 4149, class: "FBA_Fees" },
];

const sumByClass = (items, valueKey) => items
  .reduce((acc, { class: type, [valueKey]: value }) => {
    acc[type] = type in acc ? acc[type] + value : value;

    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(sumByClass(data, "revenue"));
```